# generated dependencies with generated files

Tags: c, makefile, code-generation, gnu-make

I'd like to use automatic dependency generation with files generated from `flex` and `bison`.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
CSRC=$(wildcard *.c)
OSRC=grammar.y scanner.l
OUTPUT_DIR="../bin"

SOLIDC_OBJS=solid_ast.o solid_strbuf.o solid_strlit.o solidc.o 
SOLIDL_OBJS=solidl.o solid_ast.o solid_strbuf.o

CFLAGS += -MD -MP
CC=clang
BISON=bison
FLEX=flex
MKDIR=mkdir -p

all: solidc

solidc: setup $(SOLIDC_OBJS)
    $(BISON) -vd grammar.y
    $(FLEX) --header-file=scanner.yy.h -o scanner.yy.c scanner.l
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$@ $(SOLIDC_OBJS) scanner.yy.o grammar.tab.o

setup:
    @$(MKDIR) $(OUTPUT_DIR)

run:
    $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(OUTPUT_NAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(wildcard $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*) $(wildcard *.o) $(wildcard *.d) \
        $(wildcard scanner.yy.*) $(wildcard grammar.tab.*) \
        $(wildcard grammar.output)

-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d) scanner.yy.d grammar.tab.d
```

But this doesn't work because `scanner.yy.d` and `grammar.tab.d` never get a chance to be generated.

What's the best way to work around this?

---

> Please note that this question is actually not the same as
>   [GNU make: Generating automatic dependencies with generated header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229561/gnu-make-generating-automatic-dependencies-with-generated-header-files),
>   because I'm using the "less efficient" `-include` method rather than
>   `sef`, in addition to lots of other things.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with flex and bison. Do the `$(FLEX)` and `$(BISON)` commands shown generate `scanner.yy.d` and `grammar.tab.d`? Or if they don't, do you know other commands that will?

Comment: No. They generate scanner.yy.c and grammar.tab.c. I guess you could manually $(CC) those?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can just make `grammar.tab.o` and `scanner.yy.o` prerequisites of `solidc`, and then the object rule will produce dependency files for them, the same as for any object.

```
SOLIDC_OBJS=solid_ast.o solid_strbuf.o solid_strlit.o solidc.o grammar.tab.o scanner.yy.o

all: solidc

grammar.tab.c: grammar.y
    $(BISON) -vd grammar.y

scanner.yy.c: scanner.l
    $(FLEX) --header-file=scanner.yy.h -o scanner.yy.c scanner.l

solidc: setup $(SOLIDC_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$@ $(SOLIDC_OBJS)
```

(We could tighten these rules up a little, but let's get them working first.)

Comment: The two actions you added don't seem to be run? Thanks, though.

Comment: This may take a few iterations. Try `rm -f grammar.tab.c ; make grammar.tab.c` and if that works, `rm -f grammar.tab.o ; make grammar.tab.o`.

Comment: How about `rm -f grammar.tab.c ; make solidc`?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What happens? And when you `make grammar.tab.o` does it build `grammar.tab.d`? When you `make solidc.o` does it build `solidc.d`? Please edit your question to add the results of these experiments.