# Creating Makefile with libraries

Tags: makefile

How can I create a simple Makefile using the below command?

```
 g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 -L/usr/lib/ -g -o exe sourc1.cpp sourc2.cpp sourc3.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lv4lconvert -pthread
```

I referenced this [link](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/arcgisdevhelp/developmentenvs/cpp/makefiles/makefile.linux.htm) but I am getting confused.

Comment: Did you read http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html ? Did you run `make -p` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
 # your Makefile

 #### variables
 RM= rm -vf
 CXX= g++
 CXXFLAGS= -Wall -g
 CPPFLAGS= -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 
 LDLIBS= -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui \
         -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d \
         -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib \
         -lopencv_legacy -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lv4lconvert 
 SOURCEFILES= sourc1.cpp sourc2.cpp sourc3.cpp 
 OBJECTFILES= $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCEFILES))
 PROGNAME= yourexe

 ### rules
 .PHONY: all clean

 all: $(PROGNAME)
 $(PROGNAME): $(OBJECTFILES)
       $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

 clean:
       $(RM) $(OBJECTFILES) $(PROGNAME)
```

Feel free to adapt. (You probably have header files, and you need to add dependencies of object files to source and to header files). Perhaps use [pkg-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) if it knows about *opencv*. Replace the initial many spaces in the rules with a tab.
Read carefully [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

If you have `sourc2.cpp` and if you have two header files `header1.hh` and `header2.hh` which are `#include`-d by `sourc2.cpp` you'll need to add the dependency rule:

```
 sourc2.o: source2.cpp header1.hh header2.hh
```

and there is a way (by passing arguments like [-M](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) or `-MD` to `gcc` thru suitable rules) to get such dependencies automatically generated, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229561/gnu-make-generating-automatic-dependencies-with-generated-header-files).

You may want to use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile`-s (e.g. as `remake -x`). Run `make -p` to understand which **rules are known to `make`**

Comment: Hi I understood about  pkg-config. But can you elaborate the line "need to add dependencies of object files to source and to header files"