# I'm having linking or compilation errors

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I am using Netbeans for my C++ project. I compiled my program using make and ran into this error:

```
collect2: error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'barn' failed
make: *** [barn] Error 1
```

Whereas, when I compiled it in a linux environment(Ubuntu to be precise), it compiled fine. What could have possibly gone wrong?

This is what I got when I typed make -n:

```
g++ -c main.cc
g++ -c Animal.cc
g++ -c Bird.cc
g++ -c Chicken.cc
g++ -c Cat.cc
g++ -c Pig.cc
g++ -o barn main.o Animal.o Bird.o Chicken.o Cat.o Pig.o Random.o
```

PS I prefer using Netbeans

Comment: Try a dry run and show us the output: make -n

Comment: Yikes.  Did that segfault happen more than once?

Comment: @aschepler yes, it's still not compiling fully

Comment: Suggesting to try also passing "-Wl,--verbose" to gcc in order to debug the linker

Comment: Compile using `g++ -Wall`. Show your version of `g++` (and possibly also of `ld`). Look also at output of  `dmesg`. Check that the error is reproducible (I'm thinking of some hardware failure; I never saw `ld` SIGSEGfaulting).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I compiled using g++ -Wall and I'm still getting the same error.  My g++ version is 4.3.4. How do I view dmesg?

Comment: Type `dmesg` in a console. Also, check that the disk is not full with `df -h; df -i` .... BTW GCC 4.3.4 is really old, consider upgrading it. Current one is 4.8.2

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch dmesg doesn't seem to work on Netbeans

Comment: Then, dont use Netbeans. Edit your files with a good editor like `emacs`. Have a `Makefile` (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) ...). Use it by compiling with `make`.

Answer (score 1):

A segment fault in the linker suggests a bug with that. This is what I would try if I were to run into this problem.

At the command line do

```
g++ -o barn main.cc Animal.cc Bird.cc Chicken.cc Cat.cc Pig.cc Random.cc
```

If that does not work, try variations like:

```
g++ -o barn main.cc Pig.cc Random.cc Animal.cc Bird.cc Chicken.cc Cat.cc
```

The order should not matter. This is just the kind of thing I would try with a mystery-meat problem like this.