# Using c library in c++ code with makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile, c-libraries

I have a C library made by cluster.h and cluster.c. I compiled that with `gcc -c cluster.c`.

I have to use a method of this library in the main class of a C++ project. This is the makefile i use:

```
abundancebin: main.o profileManager.o myHash.o myMalloc.o myStack.o myStringHash.o
    g++ -o abundancebin main.o profileManager.o myHash.o myMalloc.o myStack.o         myStringHash.o
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
profileManager.o: profileManager.cpp
    g++ -c profileManager.cpp
myHash.o: myHash.cpp
    g++ -c myHash.cpp
myMalloc.o: myMalloc.cpp
    g++ -c myMalloc.cpp
myStack.o: myStack.cpp
    g++ -c myStack.cpp
myStringHash.o: myStringHash.cpp
    g++ -c myStringHash.cpp

clean:
    -rm *.o abundancebin
```

I tried to import the C library in main.cpp using after other imports:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <cluster.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

but when i compile with `make` i have this response:

`main.cpp:29:21: fatal error: cluster.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cluster.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1`

if i use "cluster.h" instead of  i have this error:

`main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf68): riferimento non definito a "kmedoids"
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf68): rilocazione adattata per troncamento: R_X86_64_PC32 contro il simbolo non definito "kmedoids"
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: bad reloc address 0x18 in section`.xdata'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [abundancebin] Error 1`

I also tried to copy the code part i need from C library to C++ project but the compiler reports many errors like this:

`error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
   vector = malloc(nnodes*sizeof(int));`

The library files are in the same folder of the project files. Can someone help?
Thank you

Comment: Try changing `<cluster.h>` to `"cluster.h"`. (Quotation marks instead of angle brackets). The angle brackets tell the compiler to search in its own directory; the quotation marks tell it to start searching in the same directory where your source file is.

Comment: Or add `-I .` to your compile flags (to add the current directory to the list of searched include paths).

Comment: Improve your `Makefile`. See e.g. [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180397/creating-makefile-with-libraries/14180540#14180540)

Comment: `invalid conversion from \`void*\` to \`int\`` is valid in C, put code causing this error in `extern "C"{}`

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't understand how to improve my makefile as the exaple

Comment: You should be compiling C source as C using GCC instead of G++, then linking the object files into your C++ executable.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I tried but give me the same errors (invalid conversion from...)

Comment: @ButchDean I already compile C source using gcc but i'm not able to link the object files in my C++ executable. Can you tell me how to to this more precisely? thank you

Comment: @leonardovet Answered below for you.

Comment: Did you actually use command `gpp`? If so, that's one of your problems, you want `gcc`. If you did use `gcc`, please fix the question.

Comment: Also, in what directory you have the `cluster.*` files? If in the same dir, note that your `clean` target will remove `cluster.o`, yet you have no rule to re-make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add some code which is wrote in c language, you have to #include it like:

```
extern "C" {   
    #include "x264.h"
}
```

which tell compiler to deal with it differently, and its not necessary to change your code to c++

1: you add your code as: `#include <cluster.h>`
its better to change it to: `#include "cluster.h"`
the different is, the second one tell the compiler to first search for your header in the current directory and then in the main c++ libraries directory

your error:

```
main.cpp:29:21: fatal error: cluster.h: No such file or directory
```

is because it can't find the header, so, if `cluster.h` is in the same directory as  `main.cpp`, use `#include "cluster.h"`
or you can use `-I.` (which tell its in the current directory) or `-I/address` to tell compiler where to look for your header

when you correct it, you get the second error, which I believe its because of your code, and I think its because of your code in `main.cpp`, and do not have anything with your cluster code, I suggest, try to post your code to find out what's the problem

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question, I would approach it something like this in the makefile:

```
all: cfile.o
    g++ main.cpp -o app

cfile.o: cluster.c cluster.h
    gcc -c cluster.c
```

Note: This assumes that everything is in the same directory, so take care to specify paths if not.

Let me know of any further errors.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understant well what to write in the makefile. Can you modify mine (or part of it) to be more clear? It's my fault if  I don't understand because I'm still not good at this and you would give me a big help! Thank you!

Comment: @leonardovet I just simplified it for you. Compare with what you have done, as well as in particular what you are doing with your main that contains the entry point - you shouldn't be linking main.o to anything. Just follow the structure I have given. I can't fix it for you because I do not have your source, so don't know what is dependent on what.

Comment: @hyde Good spot! I forgot the output executable. Fixed the code.

Comment: You run the makefile again.

Comment: It all depends on the dependencies of the source files. I gave a simple example, but beyond the information given there is nothing to go on. For instance the example I gave depends on cluster.h being included in main.cpp - it was an example of how to structure the makefile, not necessarily magically fix everything. That is why I made the note of being notified of any specific errors.

Comment: Commands for target `all` will be done even if nothing is changed (because there's no file with that name, it is a *phony* target), which kind of defeats the purpose of using Makefile. `all` should usually depend on actual files, `app` in this case, and not have any commands under itself. Also, probably just "typo", but the command to build `app` does not include `ofile.o`.