# Linux g++ compiling error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/include

Tags: c++, linux, g++, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am working on a project in which `protobuf` and `zmq` are involved. I have finished it on VS2010 and now want to make it work under Linux. I just installed `protobuf` and `zmq` on our Linux server and the `Makefile` looks like this:

```
g++ -c  -D_DEBUG TestTDFAPI_v2.cpp -I ../
g++ -c  -D_DEBUG Platform.cpp
g++ -c  -D_DEBUG PathHelper.cpp                                                                                                    
g++ -c  -D_DEBUG MyStruct.pb.cpp            
g++ -c  -D_DEBUG MyStruct.cpp
g++ -o Test_TDFAPI_v2 Platform.o PathHelper.o MyStruct.pb.o MyStruct.o TestTDFAPI_v2.o -l /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -L../ -L../linux/ -lTDFAPI_v2 -lWHNetWork -lpthread -lprotobuf
```

After make, I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/include
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Use `-I` not `-l`.  The latter indicates a library to link, not an include path.

Comment: BTW, your `Makefile` looks terribly bad. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108). You want to compile with `g++ -Wall -g`.

Comment: Ah, no wonder. Thanks!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This is not written by me....I am using other's API and this is one Makefile by them....

Comment: You still should improve their `Makefile` if it is so bad.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It looks tidy...Could you explain why it is not good? I am not quite familiar with the Makefile.

Comment: Your `Makefile` is too long, but has wired-in too many things, and does not use `make` variables. Other users of your `Makefile` would try e.g. `make CXXFLAGS=-Wall` without success. So write your `Makefile` according to established *conventions*. Also, you *always must* compile with `-Wall -g` your debugging variant!

Answer (score 4):

`-l` (minus ell) is for library files to search for resolving references, you want `-I` (minus eye) to specify include directories.

Comment: Thanks for answering. BTW, what is the difference between the `-L /path/to/some/dir/` and `-L/path/to/some/dir`? Does the omit of the space following `-L` make any difference?

Comment: No, no difference with `-L` with or without space.