# compile and run with makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to using makefiles. I have four files and one of them is a header file. And i want to write the command in the terminal: **make do nu=20**. This should compile all the files and the c++ program whereas nu=20 is for the argc and argv variables in the main function.

But errors occur, that is they aren't linking properly. Here's the makefile
Sorry, for mistakes, but i am pretty new to this stuff. How should it really be written?

```
nu = 15

main.o: main.cpp ballbounce.h threads.cpp GUI.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp

threads.o: threads.cpp ballbounce.h main.cpp GUI.cpp
        g++ -c threads.cpp

GUI.o: GUI.cpp ball.h main.cpp threads.cpp
        g++ -c GUI.cpp

run: main.o threads.o GUI.o ball.h
        g++ -o run main.o threads.o GUI.o

do: run
  ./run $(nu)

clean:
        rm main.o threads.o GUI.o run
```

Comment: Improve your `Makefile` to use conventional make variables and to compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108); you probably need some GUI toolkit (e.g. [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)...). **Edit your question to improve it** (explain on which OS, with which graphical toolkit, what is `GUI.cpp`, and *give the error messages* etc...)

Comment: Depending on the shell, you might be able to say `nu=20 make run`. But you have to remove `nu=15` from the makefile.

Comment: @junchopanza: this is probably not the issue. I guess that he is using some graphical library, but does not link it (and perhaps missing `-I` compilation flags), so the *compilation fails*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Good point. But the whole paragraph is about setting some value of `nu` from the command-line  invocation of make.

Comment: But in `make do nu=20`  the `nu=20` (for the *make* variable `nu`, not a *shell* variable) is processed by `make` so is not depending of the shell, and there is no need to remove `nu=15` in the `Makefile` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Edit your lines in `makefile` to be like this

```
do: run
    ./run ${nu}
```

And then do the call

```
make do nu=20
```

When you will call it like this `nu` will be `20`, and when you call make without providing `nu`

```
make do
```

`nu` will be `15` (as you declare it in `makefile`, like default value)

Comment: That helped with the variable problem. By the way, I hadn't included some library files.