# Create and destroy an object in a loop

Tags: c++, object

I am new to C++/stacko and want to principally:

1. Create an object
2. Read in an enormous amount of data for that
3. After calculating that object's score, print it out
4. Delete the object from memory because each object has a lot of variables attributed to it
5. Loop it 1000 times

It seems simple enough but after looking around I see things about destructors but I don't know if that's what I am looking for.

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    applicants object1;
    object1.readin();
    cout<<object1.calculate();
    //How do I delete object1 and start again?
}
```

Thank you so much for any help. I don't know hardly anything about this language. Also, do I even need objects? I'm confused

Comment: The code so far is good. At the end of the block (the loop body) your `object1` is destroyed, i.e. its destructor is invoked. Mostly that's automatic, and if you use e.g. `std::vector` for your data you don't have think about it.

Comment: Your object are created on the stack hence will destruct automatically once it's goes out of the scope, which happens after each loop.

Comment: Unless he is using a pointer to dynamic memory. You should better give us the declaration of 'applicants'.

Comment: You couldn't be bothered to write out "Stack Overflow" in full?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can I be a part of the cool guys now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to delete object1.

For every iteration of the loop, a new object object1 will be created (using default constructor) and destructed after the "cout" statement.

Comment: This is true because the object is directly on the stack, not allocated on the heap with a pointer (via `new`).

Objects made with `new` need to be `delete`d.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call the destructor of `object1`, it would be called at the end of the loop body.

Technically, destructors are called at the end (right brace) of the block declaring the object.

This is why the right brace `}` is sometimes jokingly called the most important statement in C++. A lot of things may happen at that time.

It is however generally considered bad style to do real computations in constructors or destructors. You want them to "allocate" and "deallocate" resources. Read more about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) and the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (or of three).

BTW, if an [exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) happens, the destructors between the `throw` and the matching `catch` are also triggered.

Please learn more about C++ [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). You probably want your `applicants` class to use some. Maybe it should contain a field of some [`std::vector` type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Also **learn [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)** (or C++14), not some older version of the standard. So use a recent compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9 at least, as `g++`, or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) 3.5 at least, as `clang++`) with the `-std=c++11` option (don't forget to enable warnings with `-Wall -Wextra`, debugging info with `-g` for debugging with `gdb`, but enable [optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) e.g. with `-O2` at least, when benchmarking). *Modern C++11* (or [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14)) *has several very important features* (missing in previous standards) *that are tremendously useful* when [programming in C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html). You probably should also use `make` ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273581/is-a-makefile-really-needed/273582) I explain why), see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) and others examples. See also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Object one will be deleted automatically when it goes out of scope at the end bracket. You are already doing it. Be wary as if you create a pointer it will not be destructed when it goes out of scope. But your current code is working fine.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm