# C++ Code for Windows & Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, console

First of, I am very new to programming, but took an interest in it. I have successfully built a C++ Console program for Windows which is a simple Database program, which can edit / delete / input entries.

I am less and less relying on Windows for day to day stuff. I had an old HP Netbook which was impossible to use with Windows, but I put in a Linux Distro and works like a charm.

As I sometimes do use Windows, as well as having built the program to use in Windows, I am wondering if the same code can be used to compile a Linux program? I could use WINE to run it but would prefer running something specific to Linux. Is this possible with the same code or would I have to make another Linux version of it?

Comment: This is highly specific to the code itself, the adoption of platform-independent standards, and the ferociousness in which you embraced the latter while building the former. If the application is GUI, barring platform-independent toolkits like Qt, you're likely out of luck. If it is console based and you were religious about staying within the language standards including its standard library, and avoided platform-specific features, you have a solid chance.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that since you are new to programming, that you did not make the extraordinary effort to make your code portable across platforms. That takes a significant skill set, especially if you are accessing external resources such as a database. So the answer is you will probably have to re-write for Linux, and specifically the database interface.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want your C++ code to be compilable both on Linux and on Windows. You'll need operating-system specific compilers for that (a different one on Linux and on Windows).

> I am wondering if the same code can be used to compile a Linux program?

The program to compile your C++ code is called a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). On Linux you will use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as the `g++` command (which you could even customize with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), but that is not for newbies), or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) as the `clang++` command. You'll use a builder like `make` (see [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273581/is-a-makefile-really-needed/273582#273582) for why, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) example). Be sure to install a recent version (GCC 4.9 or Clang 3.5 at least in start of 2015) to get good [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) support. Focus on learning C++11 (or C++14) not some earlier variant (so use a C++11 compiler).

<sup>I don't know Windows so I cannot recommend any good C++ compiler for it (but I heard of [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), [CygWin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and of [Microsoft Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B); look also into recent [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html)...).</sup>

You might be interested in cross-platform C++ framework libraries like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) (and perhaps also [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) for database related stuff). They will help you to code some C++ usable on both systems (after recompilation).

BTW, you can always encapsulate your system specific code with preprocessor directives à la `#if LINUX` ;take care of putting all the OS specific (or OS related) code in a few source files.

It could happen (and I wish that for you) that you get fond & happy of Linux and will, in a few months, prefer to code for Linux only (you'll then install Linux on all your machines). BTW, study the source code of existing [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) you like and use on Linux. That will teach you a lot.

The advices I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28651503/841108) are still relevant today when coding on Linux. Read also something about [porting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) & [portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability), and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).