# Makefile: multiple definition of '_start'

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile has a problem.

```
eos$ make
gcc objects.o -o bumper_cars
objects.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
objects.o: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
objects.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0):     first defined here
objects.o: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
objects.o:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
objects.o: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of     `__DTOR_END__'
objects.o:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in objects.o(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And the makefile:

```
CC =  gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99 -g -pthread

all: objects.o bumper_cars

objects.o: bumper_cars.c sleeper.c sleeper.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -c

bumper_cars: objects.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f bumper_cars.o
    rm -f bumper_cars
```

Comment: I think you need to post the soruce files.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have not defined your header file with #ifndef _HEADER_FILE_NAME

Comment: Adapt [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) to suite your needs .... use `CC=gcc`  and `.c`  instead of `.cpp`  suffix

Comment: Does this happen if you run `make clean` and then run `make` again? Can you get the full `make` output from that run? Does removing `sleeper.h` from the `objects.o` prerequisites help anything?

Comment: Added the source files. Make clean/make does not do anything unfortunately. And I will look at that example, thank you, Basile.

Comment: And you're sure sleeper.c was compiled after you commented out main()?

Comment: Please remove all the .o files and show the output when make is run in a clean environment.

Comment: The output is the exact same after cleaning and remaking. And I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I tried commenting out main and got this error instead:
    eos$ make ;
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -g -pthread bumper_cars.c sleeper.c sleeper.h -o objects.o -c ;
    gcc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files

Comment: for others with a similar problem, check if you are using the -o flag correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to everything you may want to know about the make utility: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html.

The posted make file has a few oops. One of those oops is that several *.c files will not make a single .o file but rather will be several .o files.

Library files are only used in the link step header files are only used in the compile step in the following, almost all compiler warnings are enabled.

I suggest using this:

```
CC     :=  gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -g
LIBS   := -lpthread
RM     := rm -f

.PHONY: all clean

NAME := bumper_cars
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJS) $(NAME)

#
# link the .o files into the target executable
#
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c sleeper.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I.


clean:
    $(RM) *.o
    $(RM) bumper_cars
```

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted but it fixed my problem! Question though-- what do the -Wextra -pedantic and -I. flags do?

Answer (score 1):

`make` is doing the following:

1. Compiles `bumper_cars.c`  into an object code which has `main` defined.
2. Then it compiles `sleeper.c` into an object code, which also, has `main` defined.

Then make combines both objects to form the binary, the problem is the linker is complaining because of the duplicate `main` functions.

Either comment out or `#ifdef` out the function in either file and re-issue `make` again.

Comment: The `main()` in `sleeper.c` is in a comment block.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not main but the `_start` symbol.