# how to construct a makefile

Tags: c++11, makefile, g++

I have 3 files.
these compile in visual studio.

in2post.cpp

long.h

long.hpp,

long.h #includes long.hpp

and both long.hpp and in2post.hpp #include in2post

my makefile looks like this

```
in2post: in2post.o
        g++  -std=c++11 -o in2post.o in2post

in2post.o: in2post.cpp long.hpp long.h
        g++ -std=c++11 -c in2post.cpp

clean:
        rm *.o in2post
```

I get

```
hook@linprog2:~>make
g++ -std=c++11 -c in2post.cpp
In file included from long.h:40:0,
                 from in2post.cpp:3:
long.hpp: In member function ârob::Long<T>& rob::Long<T>::operator=(rob::Long<T>&&)â:
Long.hpp:36:1: error: expected â;â before â}â token
 }
 ^
makefile:5: recipe for target 'in2post.o' failed
make: *** [in2post.o] Error 1
hook@linprog2:~>nano makefile
```

Comment: That error message just means `make` has quit because the recipe for target `inpost.o` has failed. To show us what actually went wrong you need to post the failing compilation command (`g++ -c ...`) and all the errors that follow from it, as output by `make`.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) example, but add `-std=c++11` to the `CXXFLAGS` flags.

Comment: `g++ -o in2post.o in2post` this wont *quite* work.

Comment: I've added -std=c++11 to both g++ commands. I'll edit the original post to what it is currently

Answer (score 0):

It seems that g++ has encountered some weird characters and can't parse the file. My advice is to open the file in a plain text editor like vim and delete&reinsert the space before `rob::Long<T>` (it may be an invisible char) and delete the character at the end of the function declaration `operator=(rob::Long<T>&&)â`.