# gcc's protobuf compilation issue

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, protocol-buffers

I am running ubuntu 16.04 with gcc.

My `q.ccp` file is

```
#include <my_messages.pb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    google::protobuf::MyMessage* logged_msg_;

    return 0;
}
```

command used for compilation:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a my_messages.pb.cc q.cpp -lpthread
```

`protoc --version` returns: `2.2.0`

gcc --version

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

compile error starts with

```
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ExtensionSet::Clear()
```

and gives undefined reference error for every function of protocol buffers.

Comment: put the libprotobuf.a after the other object files that need it. Shouldn't it be the argument to a -l option?

Answer (score 3):

Order of arguments to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) matters a lot (libraries should go after object files and source files). You probably want

```
g++ -Wall -m64 -O1 -g -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib/ \
     my_messages.pb.cc q.cpp -lprotobuf -lpthread
```

(I would believe that `-Wl,-O1` is wrong and useless, but I leave you to check that)

Take some time to read the [GCC command options chapter](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) of the documentation. You might want to (temporarily) use `g++ -v` instead of `g++` in the command above to understand what is going on.

You probably should use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) for your build. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) of `Makefile` for inspiration. Spend some time to read [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) of `make`.