# g++ does not produce debug symbols

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am learning linux, and my first step is to adapt my [project](https://github.com/LmTinyToon/TinyRender) for running on linux. Here is simple makefile (in educational purposes mostly), which generates out file:

```
#------------------------BUILD VARIABLES-----------------------------
#   Directories, containing headers
INCLUDE_DIR = ../Include/
#   Output directory which will contain output compiled file
OUTPUT_DIR = ../Bin/Debug/

SOURCES = EngineManager.cpp Geometry.cpp Main.cpp Model.cpp \
      Shaders.cpp TGAImage.cpp 

HEADERS = EngineManager.h Geometry.h Line.h Model.h Shaders.h \
      TGAImage.h Triangle.h

#------------------------BUILD_RULES---------------------------------
TinyRenderBuilding : $(addprefix $(INCLUDE_DIR), $(HEADERS)) $(SOURCES)
    mkdir -p  $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    g++ -std=c++14 -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)TinyRender.out -g -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) $(SOURCES)
```

I cannot understand, why does `g++` not generate debug symbols? `-g` option is presented

Comment: Try using -ggdb flag instead of just -g.

Comment: How are you sure that debug information in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format is not generated? What is your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) version? Try using `g++ -v`. **Edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Did you remove all object files before build (try `make clean`) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, no I don't use make clean. I checked debug symbols in following way - just sarched pdb files (in WINDOWS analogue)

Comment: Your `Makefile` in github is very incomplete. Read about [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) (so spend a few hours reading that). No need to put the object files in some other directory.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, it seems like `-g` works, As I understand pdb information is embedded into `.out` file? (this behaviour is different from Windows)

Comment: Linux is not Windows, sorry about that. You need to learn more. Don't adapt your Windows build to Linux, but write a fresh `Makefile` from scratch, perhaps with a simpler source directory organization. Having `Source` and `Includes` subdirectories is just confusing you. Consider, for a small project like yours, a flat source file tree. Look into other free software projects for inspiration.

Comment: Of course, once you've got a big project (of nearly a million lines of C++ code) you'll organize it more wisely and you'll spend days to improve its build. But you are not there yet (you'll need many years to reach such a project size).

Comment: Linux don't use any `pdb` file (and I never heard of that). The DWARF debug information is often inside the `.o` object files (there is some weird way to get it elsewhere, I never did that) so inside your ELF executable.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Yes it is likely so. I repeated process, and gdb tells that debug information is loaded. It is very unusual for me. I need learn more about linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your makefile `g++` should produce debug symbols (`-g` option is presented). To confirm this you can run `file` on resulting binary:

```
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=9fe588c18099ef418daf288931bb033cc287922e, with debug_info, not stripped
```

(Note `with debug_info` string in output)

Answer (score 7):

To include debug symbols when compiling with `g++` you need to pass the `-g` option.

In a make make file this usually means adding it to to `CXXFLAGS`.

Also make sure you pass the `-g` option when you create the executable: when you compile you turn `.cpp` files into `.o` files, when you do the linking you turn those `.o` files into your executable).

If you change the options before running `make` again be sure to run a `make clean` cause otherwise it won't get recompiled.

Finally, make sure that you do not have additional steps like `strips` command run on the executable (which would remove debugging symbols).

you can use

```sh
objdump --syms <executable-file>
```

to check if an executable have symbols.

when it doesn't have symbols it will say something like:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

(I'm no experto of C / C++ programming, I just run into this while I was trying to debug someone else code)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure, but you can try -g or -ggdb.You can do some research on these. We were using these parameters to debug the C program with the gdb tool.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not setting the `-s` option for `ld` or in `LDFLAGS`

```
       -s
       --strip-all
           Omit all symbol information from the output file.
```