# Makefile does not create to the right folder

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following project directory structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 account Domain Users     0 Aug 20 16:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 account Domain Users     0 Aug 20 08:48 ../
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 account Domain Users     0 Aug 20 10:55 include/
-rw-r--r--  1 account Domain Users   597 Aug 20 16:16 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 account Domain Users     0 Aug 20 10:55 obj/
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 account Domain Users     0 Aug 20 10:55 src/
```

in the src folder: `main.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp`

in the include folder: `foo.h bar.h`

When I run the following Makefile, the object files are created in the project directory, not the `obj` directory as I might expect from my Makefile:

```
1 ODIR = obj
2 SDIR = src
3 IDIR = include
4
5 _OBJS = main.o foo.o bar.o
6 OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJS))
7
8 CC = g++
9
10 CFLAGS = -w
11
12 PROG = program
13
14 #VPATH = src:include:obj:../src:../include:../obj
15
16 all: $(OBJS)
17     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)
18
19 $(ODIR)/main.o: $(SDIR)/main.cpp $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
20     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $(SDIR)/main.cpp
21
22 $(ODIR)/foo.o: $(SDIR)/foo.cpp $(IDIR)/foo.h
23     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $(SDIR)/foo.cpp
24
25 $(ODIR)/bar.o: $(SDIR)/bar.cpp $(IDIR)/bar.h
26     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $(SDIR)/bar.cpp
27
28 clean:
29     rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

Can anybody clue me in on why this is happening? My linker doesn't see the object files because it thinks the files are in the obj directory.

Comment: `-o $@` would seem to be missing from your flags for each .o rule. As in `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c -o $@ $(SDIR)/main.cpp`. See [Automatic variables in Gnu make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for other handy vars.

Comment: Try [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x`

Comment: After you follow @WhozCraig's advice (which should be worked into an answer), you can collapse the three object rules (`$(ODIR)/main.o`, `$(ODIR)/foo.o` and `$(ODIR)/bar.o`) into one rule.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! This worked! Can you make this into an answer so I can accept it? And elaborate for other newbies (%@ contains the whole path+file, whereas leaving it out means just the file)

Comment: @Beta How would I collapse them into one rule? They have different dependencies, main depends on [foo.h, bar.h], foo depends on [foo.h], bar depends on [bar.h]. (As you can see, I'm still very new to self-compiling without using an IDE, stuff like this confuse me)

Comment: Don't feel bad about being confused-- Make is a tricky tool with a hard learning curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target specifier for your compilation commands is missing. ex: When executing this:

```
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $(SDIR)/main.cpp
```

there is no target so the default is the current working directory (in your case, the root folder where you Makefile resides.

Gnu make provides a *plethora* of automatic variables for substitution in recipes, each to provide some particle of the recipe for your use in forming your commands. [**See here**](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for the full gambit, but I believe you'll want something like this:

```
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c -o $@ $(SDIR)/main.cpp
```

From the Gnu documentation :

> `$@`
>
> The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an
>   archive member, then `$@` is the name of the archive file. In a
>   pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern
>   Rules), `$@` is the name of whichever target caused the rule's recipe
>   to be run.

Or something similar to that.

On a separate note, there are a multitude of ways for building automatic dependencies for your projects. One common method (though a wee bit hard to follow) is presented [in this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229561/gnu-make-generating-automatic-dependencies-with-generated-header-files). The question itself is based on [this paper discussing automatic dependency generation techniques](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html).

It fundamentally comes down to generating a `.d` file for each source file, and within the .d file is a list of header files generated via the `-MMD` command switch option. Describing i in detail is beyond the scope of this question/answer, but definitely take a look and do a little googling on the subject. Between gnu-make and the dependency generator for cc, you can build some remarkably simply Makefile's that do an incredible amount of work for you auto-magically.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a little on WhozCraig's answer:

Start with this rule:

```
$(ODIR)/main.o: $(SDIR)/main.cpp $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $(SDIR)/main.cpp
```

The command (`$(CC) ...`) doesn't specify an output file, so he compiler will put the resultant object file (`main.o`) in the working directory, which is the directory in which you invoked Make, which is the project directory. **Note that Make and the compiler don't talk to each other very much.** The compiler knows what source files it should scan, but nobody told it anything about `obj/`, so it infers the destination file name (`main.o`) from the name of the source file; Make knows that the target should be `obj/main.o`, but it doesn't know what the compiler is actually doing. (In fact, it doesn't know that the command it's executing invokes a compiler.)

We can fix this problem by adding a term to the command, specifying the destination file name:

```
$(ODIR)/main.o: $(SDIR)/main.cpp $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $(SDIR)/main.cpp -o $(ODIR)/main.o
```

Now the compiler will put `main.o` in the right place-- and Make doesn't notice any difference, it's still just passing a command to the shell.

We notice a lot of redundancy in this rule (e.g. `$(ODIR)/main.o` spelled out twice), so we reduce it by using [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
$(ODIR)/main.o: $(SDIR)/main.cpp $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $< -o $@
```

Where `$<` expands to the first thing in the prerequisite list (namely `$(SDIR)/main.cpp`), and `$@` expands to the target name (namely `$(ODIR)/main.o`). And for reasons that will become clear in a minute, we split the header dependencies into a separate rule for the same target:

```
$(ODIR)/main.o: $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h

$(ODIR)/main.o: $(SDIR)/main.cpp $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $< -o $@
```

[Yes, we can do that.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Rules)

Now we look at the object rules:

```
$(ODIR)/main.o: $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
$(ODIR)/foo.o: $(IDIR)/foo.h
$(ODIR)/bar.o: $(IDIR)/bar.h

$(ODIR)/main.o: $(SDIR)/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $< -o $@

$(ODIR)/foo.o: $(SDIR)/foo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $< -o $@

$(ODIR)/bar.o: $(SDIR)/bar.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $< -o $@
```

Again we see redundancy-- the last three rules are almost identical! We can make them into a single [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
$(ODIR)/main.o: $(IDIR)/foo.h $(IDIR)/bar.h
$(ODIR)/foo.o: $(IDIR)/foo.h
$(ODIR)/bar.o: $(IDIR)/bar.h

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(IDIR) -c $< -o $@
```

We could go even further, but that's enough for one day.

Comment: +1 totally worth the up-vote for the extra mile of work. I haven't got the initiative to roll the full dependency-generation gauntlet at this, but this gets one step closer. nice job.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thank you. The full dependency-generation gauntlet is a thing of beauty, but the OP isn't ready; first exposure to it can give even an experienced user whiplash.